# Two books in one volume with sequential number pages but separate chapter numbering

Tags: book-design

I am translating a volume including two books with sequencial number pages but separate chapter numbering for each book.

What I would like to do is best illustrated by this skeleton table of contents:

CONTENTS

First title

Preface

1. Introduction
2. First chapter
3. Middle chapter
4. Last chapter

Second title

1. Introduction
2. First chapter
3. Middle chapter
4. Last chapter

Index

Appendix

What would be a sane approach?  I know about the book, scrbook and tufte-book classes, but I haven’t been able to research more about each’s workings yet.

Comment: `memoir` seems one of the most natural choices here, since it has a `\book` sectional unit.

Comment: Did not know about that, thank you very much!

Comment: `memoir` can be used even with sequential page numbering: use `\begin{titlingpage*}` environment to not reset the page number on subsequent titles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is based on an answer by Gonzalo Medina which disappeared.

I am not entirely sure how you want the numbering to go with respect to front matter. This may therefore not be quite right because I've basically set the page numbering to arabic straight through:

[image: 2 in 1]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{chapter}{book}
\makeatother
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand*\pagenumbering[1]{\relax}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\book{First title}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Third chapter}

\book{Second title}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Third chapter}

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

The page numbering could, however, be adjusted as required. For example, you could just use

```
\let\oldpagenumbering\pagenumbering
\newcounter{savedpage}
\renewcommand*\pagenumbering[1]{%
  \setcounter{savedpage}{\value{page}}%
  \oldpagenumbering{#1}%
  \setcounter{page}{\value{savedpage}}%
  }
```

before the second book to keep the standard roman page numbering for the front matter of the first one. (I notice your schema didn't include a preface for the second book.) However, this looks a little odd with respect to the page numbers for the books themselves.

Or you could move

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand*\pagenumbering[1]{\relax}
```

after the `\tableofcontents*` so that the table of contents gets a roman page number.

Comment: when you reach `10000` you can see deleted answers :)

Comment: @cmhughes There's an incentive! Should I ever reach such lofty heights I'll be able to see all the stuff other people don't think is worth leaving around in addition to my own ;). But it won't help solve the problem of giving credit since nobody with less than 10,000 can see what you are talking about. At least, I assume not... Incidentally, what should happen to the page numbering of the front matter in this case? It looks strange to have roman in the middle if arabic is numbering sequentially...

Comment: @cfr, you nailed it.  Wonderful.

Just a small note: the lines on pagenumbering produced pages containing a section name and the words ‘arabic’ or ‘roman’, so I just deleted them.  I will leave this and other style adjustments for later on.

Thank you very much!

Comment: @lfd How odd. Anyway, I'm glad it solved the immediate problem :). Edit: Oh, no. Wait - I see. I forgot about the argument...

Comment: @lfd See my edit. I think this should fix the problem. I forgot (for some reason) that `\pagenumbering` takes an argument so needs to be redefined properly to account for that argument. Otherwise TeX deals with the argument separately which means it just typesets its literal value e.g. `arabic` or `roman`.